# How can I adjust datetime length in JPA?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

basically added datetime(6) in JPA without any settings.
but I want to datetime, not datetime(6).
so I tried under line code

```java
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "reg_datetime", nullable = false, length=0)
private Date regDateTime;
```

then came out like this ddl

```sql
create table school (
       id bigint not null auto_increment,
        address varchar(255),
        mod_datetime DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
        name varchar(20) not null,
        reg_datetime datetime(6) not null,
        primary key (id)
    ) engine=InnoDB
```

there is the super easy way under line code
but is it the only way?

```java
@CreationTimestamp
@Column(name = "reg_datetime", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
private LocalDateTime regDateTime;
```